# Not able to expose spring boot port in aws ec2 to outer world

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I am running spring boot app on aws on port 8443. But I am not able to ping it from outside world

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1305/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24449/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24449/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24449/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12632/nginx.conf
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1305/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           927/dhclient
```

My inbound security group rules

```
Type
Protocol
Port range
Source
Description - optional
HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0   -
SSH TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0   -
Custom TCP  TCP 8443    0.0.0.0/0   -
```

My inbound network Acl

```
Rule #
Type
Protocol
Port Range
Source
Allow / Deny
100
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW
*
ALL Traffic
ALL
ALL
0.0.0.0/0
DENY
```

While doing telnet inside the container on port 8443 works. But on doing telnet from my local by ip on 8443 fails.

Comment: Please attach outbound network ACL also

Comment: Do you use public IP on the EC2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my local computer's firewall was stopping the connection. I checked with another laptop and I was able to connect.